# Iterating over only a subset of elements in set

Tags: c#, set

I want to iterate over only a certain elements in a set without having to modify the set or create a new one every time. For context, this is for a game.

Let's say we have a set of entities on the screen S = { A, B, C, D }.
Each entity will affect other entities in a certain way. So, A will affect all entities in the set S, except itself.

Since all entities share the same set, I don't want to need to make a new set for all of them, which is missing just the entity itself. What's more, I'd like to have certain entities NOT affect other certain entities. These entities would be included in that entity's Exclude set (example: B's exclude set = { D }, so, B will affect { A, C }.

I'd rather not check at every iteration if the element exists in the exclude set, and removing each entity from the communal set before the loop and added them again seems wrong. Also, another obvious thing to do is to make each entity hold a set of things to iterator over (excluding itself and any excluded entities), but it again seems bad seeing as most entity's sets will be almost the exact same as the communal set, and I would have to sync all these sets when entities are added and removed from the screen. Not to mention that when there are 10,000 entities on the screen, that's a lot of extra sets. Maybe I'm over thinking the space/time costs here, but I feel as though there is a more elegant way to handle this.

Comment: Remember, that you don't copy the entire set. Just the reference. That's not that much.

Comment: That's true. I guess I'm just worried about the fact that they all need to be synced to the 'master set' under that approach. So, when adding an element to the game, you must add to all sets instead of just the master. I've found an ObservableSet implementation online that can make that easy, although it adds a slight amount of overhead to adding/removing any elements to the set. I'm happy about Contains being lightning fast though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to be able to perform some `operation` on all elements in the set, except the one  `"acting" element`, and a selected few other elements that are in the acting element's `exclude-list`, is that right?

If that is correct, then you can include each element in it's own exclusion list, along with any other elements it should exclude, and iterate over all elements that are not in that list.

Simplified in pseudo code:

```
var originalSet = { A, B, C, D, E }
var excludeListForA = {A, B, C} // <-- Note that A is in it's own list!

// To update D and E:
var setToActOn = originalSet.Where(element => excludeListForA.Contains(element));
```

As long as you now only work with references, you should be able to change elements in `setToActOn` to update the correct elements in `originalSet`.

Comment: This looks clean, but I'm starting to fear I don't understand linq. Wouldn't .Where need to check every element in the originalSet exclude the elements in the exclusionList, which I can THEN iterate on? If so, this would be significantly slower than just keeping a subset for each entity(which wouldn't contain itself and any excluded entities) and do one quick iteration over that set. (although in that case I must take the hit on speed when adding to the originalSet, requiring a sync to all sets on all entities).

Comment: Although, I could do just that with the above code only when the exclusionset or the masterset changes... instead of every iteration...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure this is what you are after but how about

```
var masterSet = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
var member = 5;
var exclusions = new List<int> { 4, 6 };

var subSet = masterSet
 .Where(x => !exclusions.Any(y => x) && x == member)
 .ToList(); // or not to list and do stuff with say Select or something
```

As it was already mentioned by Marcin this will only operate on references. Hence the real overhead here ()as far as I know) is from LINQ iterations.

Of course the type of the collection will be different and comparison clause may need to change too.

Comment: Although this would work, it seems as though we'd need to iterate over the entire masterSet at every iteration to produce the subSet, even in cases where there was only, say, 1 or 2 entities out of 1000 that we wanted to omit, which seems too costly.

Comment: In that case I suppose some sort of a matrix of sets / sub sets can be constructed when master set is loaded. Of course if exclusion sets change over time I can't think of another way to deal with this.